# nmcli eqivalent of ip route add command for interface routing

Tags: linux-networking, nmcli

I can add route over the interface using ip route add command, for example:

`ip r a 1.1.244.244/32 dev main-br`

How to achieve the same using nmcli?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A search for `nmcli add route` brings us to [this documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/networking_guide/sec-configuring_static_routes_using_nmcli), which says that we can add a static route like this:

```
nmcli connection modify enp1s0 +ipv4.routes "192.168.122.0/24 10.10.10.1"
```

Experimenting with that command, it looks like if you want to specify a device route as in your example, you can simply leave out the nexthop address, giving you:

```
nmcli connection modify enp1s0 +ipv4.routes "192.168.122.0/24"
```

Or in your case:

```
nmcli connection modify <connection_name> +ipv4.routes 1.1.244.244/32
```

Where you would replace `<connection_name>` with the name of the networkmanager connection associated with device `main-br`.

Comment: I have the same requirement as OP. That is, this works: 
ip route add 192.168.39.11/32 dev br0

the nmcli connection name is also br0.

`nmcli connection modify br0 +ipv4.routes 192.168.39.11/32`
but the bridge breaks now. The VM can not connect.

the br0.nmconnection now has this:
`[ipv4]
method=auto
route1=192.168.39.11/32
`